# Why is a non-dependency preserving BCNF decomposition still considered to be in BCNF?

Tags: database-design, bcnf

From the *Database Systems Concept* textbook, for a schema ***r*** with the set of dependencies ***F*** to be considered in BCNF, for all dependencies in ***F+*** (i.e. the closure of ***F***) of the form *a → b*, at least one of the following must be true:

- *a → b* is a trivial functional dependency (*b* ⊆ *a*)
- *a* is a superkey for schema ***r***

The example that the textbook gives is that for a schema **dept_advisor** (*s_ID,i_ID,dept_name*) with the functional dependencies ***F*** = {*i_ID → dept_name; s_ID, dept_name → i_ID*}, the BCNF decomposition would be:

- **r1** (*s_ID, i_ID*)
- **r2** (*i_ID, dept_name*)

This decomposition fulfills the 1st dependency (*i_ID → dept_name*) since *i_ID* is a superkey for **r2**, but since it doesn't satisfy the 2nd dependency (*s_ID, dept_name → i_ID*, hence being non-dependency preserving), doesn't this decomposition not adhere to BCNF since the 2nd dependency is nontrivial but is not a superkey for the schema of the decomposition?

Comment: Noted, I've reworded the terms in my original question. When you say that "the 2nd FD doesn't hold in either table", do you mean that because (s_ID, dept_name → i_ID) doesn't hold for either r1 nor r2, it shouldn't be considered as one of the dependencies that need to adhere to the requirement that it be either nontrivial or a superkey?

Comment: Yes. An FD denotes a statement. We say a statement holds or is satisfied or is the case etc when/iff it is true. For an FD to hold its attributes have to all be in the table. Neither table has all attributes of the 2nd FD. So it cannot hold in either. Now re your reasoning: Your last sentence's "since" fails to use the "holds" part of the definition. Since the FD doesn't hold, it's not in F+, so it's not among the "all FDs in F+", so whether it satisfies no definition bullet is irrelevant. PS Your last paragraph is sloppy. Verbs don't always have the right kind of thing as subject & object.

Comment: That textbook does not give a correct definition of BCNF. Technically, they define when a table is "in BCNF with respect to set F" but then don't go on to actually define BCNF. For BCNF: If F had to be the set of FDs that hold then it would *be* F+ by definition. They don't mean that F has to be *some* FDs that hold, because then other FDs could hold than the ones in F+ that violate the bullet test & BCNF. What is correct is, F has to be *a cover for the FDs that hold*. But they don't say that. They don't even say that the FDs in F have to hold! You have my sympathies. PS So *you are right*!

Comment: PS (By "you are right" I mean, right that "this decomposition [does] not adhere to [that incorrect definition of] BCNF".) From Fundamentals of Database Systems 6th 2011 Elmasri, Navathe (Pearson AW): "**Definition.** A relation schema R is in **BCNF** if whenever a *nontrivial* FD X→A holds in R, then X is a superkey of R." (We need *all* the FDs that hold.) (*Before* its definition your text says "Given that a set of FDs *F* holds [...] We will use the notation *F+* to denote the **closure** of the set F [...]". But F+ is only all the FDs that hold if F is a cover for all the FDs hold.)

Comment: Update: Your textbook's notion of "schema" is a base table's declared definitions & constraints. So "the" FDs of a schema are taken to be a cover for all the ones that hold--since those ones hold, the ones in their closure hold, and no others hold. Interpreting F this way, the 2nd FD doesn't hold so isn't in F or F+. (The textbook phrasing is still peculiar--Technically, they define when a table is "in BCNF with respect to set F".) (I rolled back the edit where you added that F is FDs "that hold" (making F=F+)--"declared to hold" would be correct, but lack of "hold" justifies your reasoning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly reported a definition for BCNF: for each non-trivial dependency of F<sup>+</sup>, the determinant is a superkey.

So, in your example, both the relation schemas in the decomposition fulfill this definition: in `r2` in the only non-trivial dependency `i_ID → dept_name` the determinant is a superkey, while in `r1` there are no non-trivial dependencies so the definition is still satisfied. So you have two schemas which are both in BCNF.

But, as again you have correctly noted, the dependency `s_ID, dept_name → i_ID` does not hold in the set of dependencies of the decomposition (even if you perform the closure of the union of the set of dependencies of the `r1` and `r2`), and this means that the decomposition does not preserve the dependencies. What this means, in practice, is that in the decomposed schema the fact that a couple of values of `s_ID` and `dept_name` could correspond to more than one value of `i_ID`, so losing an important integrity contraint.

What this example can teach us? That we can have a decomposition of a schema in BCNF which produces a database that could contain inconsistent data. And note that in this particular case there is *no* decomposition in BCNF that can preserve the dependencies. So BCNF is not a panacea for eliminating all problems in database design, and in fact other normal forms have been defined and can be used to alleviate several problems of database design. For instance, the original schema of the example is already in Third Normal Form (3NF), and this is considered acceptable in practical situations.

Comment: Although I agree with your gist, the question's BCNF definition is *not* correct, it doesn't say F is the set of *FDs that hold*, and that missing part is fundamental to the asker's confusion, along with vague terms "break" & "violate" that if made clear would refer to *FDs that hold*.

Comment: Thanks for the input! There's still 1 point I don't completely understand though: you mentioned that `r1` only contains trivial dependencies, but I not sure I see that since *i_ID* doesn't seem to be a subset of *s_ID*

Comment: @LYC Please explain your "since"--it doesn't make sense. You say you're not sure r1 only "contains" (satisfies?) trivial FDs, so that means you think it might "contain" a non-trivial FD. But what does "i_ID doesn't seem to be a subset of s_ID" have to do with that? (In case you are saying something about the 2nd FD, the reason *it* is not trivial is because *{i_ID}* is not a subset of *{s_ID, dept_name}*.)

Comment: @LYC, in `r1` there are only the attributes `s_ID` and `i_ID`. Given the dependencies that hold in `r`, no such dependency hold in `r1`, and no non-trivial dependency derived  from those can hold in `r1`. Which are all the dependencies that hold in it? Here is a list: `i_ID → i_ID; 
i_ID → ;
s_ID → s_ID; 
s_ID → ;
i_ID, s_ID → i_ID, s_ID`. And you can see that they are all trivial dependencies.

Comment: @LYC & Renzo And `{} → {}`.